# solr rank value mismatch in exact phrase search

Tags: solr, lucene, solrj, solr4

Ex : 
    skills :( ( "Data Warehouse") )^10.0

```
its returns 40 but i expacted only 10
```

My Solr Version 3.1 and  I overwrite DefaultSimilarity of solr using following link ([Solr Custom Similarity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20428709/solr-custom-similarity))

**schema.xml**

*fieldType*

```
<fieldType name="text_rc" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" autoGeneratePhraseQueries="true">
  <analyzer type="index">        
    <tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern="[\s|,]+" />         
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
    <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="char_mapping.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>        
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="0" splitOnNumerics="0"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">     
    <tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern="[\s|,]+" />      
<filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
<charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="char_mapping.txt"/>        
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="0" splitOnNumerics="0"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/> 
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

*field*

```
<field name="skills" type="text_rc" indexed="true" stored="false" required="false" multiValued="true" />
```

**Solr Admin Page result**

```
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader">
    <int name="status">0</int>
    <int name="QTime">37</int>
    <lst name="params">
        <str name="indent">on</str>
        <str name="rows">10</str>
        <str name="start">0</str>
        <str name="version">2.2</str>
        <str name="q">skills :( ( "Data Warehouse") )^10.0 </str>
    </lst>
</lst>
<result name="response" numFound="1" start="0" maxScore="40.0">
    <doc><float name="score">40.0</float>
        <str name="empid">1001</str>
    </doc>
</result>
```

**MY debug Query Result**

localhost:8080/solr/core0/select?skills+:(+(+"Data+Warehouse"+)+)^10.0)+&debugQuery=on

```
40.0 = (MATCH) sum of:
  40.0 = (MATCH) weight(skills:"data warehouse" in 0), product of:

   20.0 = queryWeight(skills:"data warehouse"), product of:
     2.0 = idf(skills: data=6 warehouse=1)
     10.0 = queryNorm

   2.0 = fieldWeight(skills:"data warehouse" in 0), product of:
     1.0 = tf(phraseFreq=2.0)
     2.0 = idf(skills: data=6 warehouse=1)
     1.0 = fieldNorm(field=skills, doc=0)
```

how to solve my problem pls guide me.

Comment: why exactly do you expect the document to score 10 instead of 40 ?

Comment: we consider "data warehouse" as a single skill keyword  instead of two words

Comment: but your tokenizer splits the string into 2 distinct tokens at both query and index time : the pattern `[\s|,]` will split on whitespace

Comment: I think the question here is why you care about the actual score rather than the order of the matched docs?

Comment: actually we are showing rank based on skills that has bean searched. since "data warehouse" is two word it's showing wrong score

Comment: i would consider indexing words you want grouped like this by concatenating them with an underscore

Comment: how concatenat my skills. i have more than 20k skills.