# How could I new parameter to TFIDF in Solr?

Tags: java, solr, lucene

I'm new in java, and my research about improvement `TF IDF` in `Solr`. My question is,

> How to add new parameter (except `Freq`) in TF method in `Solr` ?

Should I do `Overloading`???
Thanks

```
@Override public float tf(float freq) {
return (float)Math.sqrt(freq);}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

[Create your own custom similarity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20428709/solr-custom-similarity), which will allow you to use any parameter / calculation for each of the different parts of the current formula for the DefaultSimilarity.

If you want to go even deeper, look at [Build your own custom lucene query and scorer](http://opensourceconnections.com/blog/2014/01/20/build-your-own-custom-lucene-query-and-scorer/).