# word proximity not working in apache solr

Tags: solr, lucene

I am using dismax parser to boost phrase queries like following

```
qf=story_title^5.0+tax_payer_name+judgement_text^1.0+story_description^1.0+tax_payer_name+nature_of_the_issues+decision_summary+additional_comments+facts_of_the_case+section_number';
pf=story_title^5.0+&pf=judgement_text+story_description^1+nature_of_the_issues+decision_summary+additional_comments+facts_of_the_case+section_number';

qs=3';
ps=3';
```

but whenever i search like **54F beed registration** , some results come up where , there are more **registration** word recurring and not **54F beed registration**

Somewhere i found that solr score depends on percentage of word repeating in document

how can we override this behavior to achieve desired results in solr?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's an `omitTermFreq` setting yet, even if it has been mentioned many times.

A possible solution is to create your own similarity class by subclassing DefaultSimilarity, and returning 1.0f as the `tf` value.

See [Solr Custom Similarity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20428709/solr-custom-similarity) for an on how to implement a custom similarity class. Recent versions of Solr (4.0+) supports a custom similarity class per field.