# How to make modifications to SOLR's tfidf similarity?

Tags: solr, lucene

I am trying to search for titles hence just the presence of the word is sufficient and its frequency is not relevant at least to my use-case.

For e.g:
the search query is: "board early with my pets"

The results I got are:
Result 1:
Pets
2.3924026

Result 2:
Pets Counts against in cabin pet limit
2.0538325

Result 3:
Pets Preboarding allowed
1.6092906

Ideally I want the result 3 to come at the top which needs some external work. However the result 1 is obvious and acceptable but the result 2 has the score of 2.05 as it has 'pet' is mentioned twice, implies the tf value is higher [2/4(after removing stop words)]. My requirement is just detect the presence of the word and not to go for word's frequency.

How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need phrase search or other functionality that depend on position data being indexed, you can use `omitTermFreqAndPositions="true"` for the field in question. In that case no position or frequency will be stored for the terms.

If that's not an option, you can create a dummy similarity class that extends DefaultSimilarity and returns 1.0f for tf. Such an example can be found in [Solr Custom Similarity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20428709/solr-custom-similarity).

You can also configure different similarity classes for each field, allowing you to drop `tf` scoring for a single field.

A third option is to use [the constant scoring operator](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_4/the-standard-query-parser.html#constant-score-with) for the part of your query that you want to have constant score. Not sure if the edismax parser supports this.