# solr 8.4.1 search ignore duplicate phrase

Tags: solr

We are using Solr 8.4.1 to search the products from documents. I want exact phrase to come on top, but I also want if same phrase is repeated many times in document then it should only be counted once. Right now those keywords having same phrase multiple times in document comes on top because they're getting a higher score.

Please see the result below given i am searching for `"pipes"`. Seven results found, but `prod_id:297720` named `my pipes pipes` have a different score from  `prod_id:3064`.

As per our need both should have the same score. I want to ignore the repeated phrase found in the documents.

We are using similarity class `<similarity class="solr.BM25SimilarityFactory"/>`

Searching field schema given below as

```
<field name="product_related_kword" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" />
```

And the result is:

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":222,
    "params":{
      "q":"product_related_kword:pipes",
      "fl":"product_name,score,product_related_kword,prod_id,member_classified_slno,member_id",
      "start":"0",
      "rows":"100",
      "debugQuery":"on"}},
  "response":{"numFound":7,"start":0,"maxScore":2.7593598,"docs":[
      {
        "prod_id":297720,
        "product_name":"my pipes pipes",
        "member_classified_slno":123457327,
        "member_id":"11111327",
        "product_related_kword":"my pipes pipes 00",
        "score":2.7593598},
      {
        "prod_id":3064,
        "product_name":"pipes",
        "member_classified_slno":123457560,
        "member_id":"11119579",
        "product_related_kword":"pipes 00",
        "score":2.5436506},
      {
        "prod_id":3064,
        "product_name":"pipes",
        "member_classified_slno":123457544,
        "member_id":"11113186",
        "product_related_kword":"pipes 00",
        "score":2.5436506},
      {
        "prod_id":3064,
        "product_name":"pipes",
        "member_classified_slno":123457546,
        "member_id":"11113636",
        "product_related_kword":"pipes 00",
        "score":2.5436506},
      {
        "prod_id":3064,
        "product_name":"pipes",
        "member_classified_slno":123457551,
        "member_id":"11119238",
        "product_related_kword":"pipes 00",
        "score":2.5436506},
      {
        "prod_id":3064,
        "product_name":"pipes",
        "member_classified_slno":123457553,
        "member_id":"785565531",
        "product_related_kword":"pipes 00",
        "score":2.5436506
       }
    ]
  },
```

Comment: I'm not sure how it behaves for phrase matches, but could you try using [the constant score operator](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_4/the-standard-query-parser.html#constant-score-with)? [Another option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51264962/how-to-make-modifications-to-solrs-tfidf-similarity/51270987#51270987) is to use a custom similarity based on BM25 but with `tf`always returning 1.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following filter to your index analyzer.

```
<filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
```

This will remove the duplicate tokens from the stream. If you have synonyms then add this after Synonym Filter for better results.

Check RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory on the following page

https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_4/filter-descriptions.html

Comment: My guess is that this will break phrases if one of the terms in the phrase has occurred earlier in the document - i.e. "pipes bar foo pipes" might not match `foo pipes` if the last `pipes` token is removed?

Comment: Yes. That's possible. May be @abhay can try and provide insights.

Comment: hi i've implemented the same bu it's not working, i'm getting the same result

Comment: Make sure you've reindexed the content after changing the definitions. Appending `debug=all` to your query should also give you information about how the score is being calculated.

Comment: Also, you can check in Analysis section to see what is actually happing while indexing and querying.